SEDE get questions that linked to questions I posted
All Stack Exchange posts display a section for "Linked" Questions to the right - which display questions whose references are added somewhere in the current post.
I would like to query a list of questions that have links to questions that are posted by me or by a specific user_id.

You can use the query below to get what you want.
The query finds all question type posts that have a link to a specific user's question in the "Linked" section. Just specify the UserId to check.
p.s. The penultimate column is the link to the question that is used in the "Linked" section. The last column is the link to the question in which this is used.
WITH user_questions AS (
  SELECT
    Id
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    PostTypeId = 1
    AND OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##
)

SELECT
  *,
  PostId AS [Post Link],
  RelatedPostId AS [Post Link]
FROM
  PostLinks
WHERE 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      user_questions
    WHERE
      user_questions.Id = PostLinks.PostId
      AND LinkTypeId = 1
  )
ORDER BY
  CreationDate DESC
;

You can check it here.
